# Pandas/numpy: Is there a way to check a string and to assign a value of the same row to another dataframe?

Tags: pandas, string, numpy, contains

I want to check if a given string is in a df and give the value of another column in this row into a different dataframe.
I tried something like this:

```
string = 'ef'
df2['value']=np.where(df1['one'].str.contains(string),df1['two'],)
```

`df1`:

| one | two |
| --- | --- |
| abc | hello |
| def | there |

In the end column `value` of Dataframe shall contain the string `there`.

`df2`:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| ef | there |
| ef | there |

Answer (score 1):

```
sring = 'ef'

df1['value'] = np.where(df1['one'].str.contains(string), df1['two'], df1['one'])

df1

   one    two  value
1  abc  hello    abc
2  def  there  there
```

Comment: thanks for your respond, but i wanted to assign it to another dataframe df2 not to the same df 1

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using *pandas*' [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) method:

```
df2 = (
    df1.assign(
        value=lambda df: df["one"].mask(df["one"].str.contains(string), df["two"])
    )
    .rename(columns={"two": "key"})
    .drop("one", axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
    key     value
0   hello   abc
1   there   there
```